# Artin's Algebra, Exercise 11.9.13

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

> Let $\varphi: \mathbb{C}[x, y] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}[t]$ be a homomorphism that is the identity on $\mathbb{C}$ and sends $x \sim x(t)$. $y \leadsto y(t)$, and such that $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are not both constant. Prove that the kernel of $\varphi$ is a principal ideal.

[Prove that the kernel of a homomorphism is a principal ideal. (Artin, Exercise 9.13)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244452)

Here is the similar question posted 9 years ago. And if I comment my approach in the comments box on this post I think it is absurd. That's why I'm posting this question again with my approach please give me hints how to approach from here.

Here is my approach:-

Consider $\varphi: \mathbb{C}[x, y] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}[t]$ be a homomorphism that is the identity on $\mathrm{C}$ and sends
$$
\begin{array}{l}
x \rightarrow x(t) \\
y \rightarrow y(t)
\end{array}
$$
and such that $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are not both constant.
To prove: The kernel of $\varphi$ is a principal ideal.
Claim: $\ker\varphi$ is principal.
If not, then $\ker\varphi$ contains two elements $f, g$ that do not have a common factor.
It is enough to show that they do not have a common factor in $\mathrm{C}(x)[y]$.
For the proof suppose that;
$$
h \in \mathbb{C}(x)[y]
$$
It is a common factor, then:
$h=a^{-1} h_{0}$ for some $a \in \mathbb{C}[x], h_{0} \in \mathbb{C}[x, y]$ by clearing denominator.

And i cannot approach from here please help me,, and if my argument is wrong then please give another hints or solution. Thank you

Comment: The 2nd answer in your link seems fine. The height of the kernel ideal (which is a prime ideal) is 1 and since $\mathbb{C}[x, y]$ is a UFD, height 1 prime ideals are principal. So you are done.

Comment: @EvansGambit if OP is studying Artin's book, it seems unlikely that they have encountered notions like height.

Comment: How do you know that a non-principal ideal contains two coprime elements?

Answer (score 1):

The ideal $(x^2,xy)$ shows that your start is wrong: it is not principal and every element of this ideal is divisible by $x$.

For an elementary approach to this problem see [here](https://brianbi.ca/artin/11.9). The main idea is to choose a polynomial $p_0\in\ker\phi$ such that $d_0=\deg_yp_0$ is minimal among the non-zero polynomials in $\ker\phi$ and the coefficient of $y^{d_0}$ has minimal degree in $x$ among the polynomials in $\ker\phi$ whose $y$-degree is $d_0$. Then show that $\ker\phi=(p_0)$ by using the long division in $\mathbb C(x)[y]$.